# How do I extend default joomla class / function?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I want to extend the submit file function in Joomla in an extension I'm making to custom handle files, how do I do that? Can I get some code samples please.

I've been told to extend them in the Model, but whenever I try to extend anything I get an error, even if I have an empty function that just says "..extends xxxx{}.

Comment: can you please provide the function and the error you receive

Comment: as Lodder said we need the error message and the code to see where your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
see below url and read :-

http://docs.joomla.org/How_Joomla_pieces_work_together

Or

class <name>Controller extends JController
{

}
```